# Android APK Distribution Without "Unknown Sources" Checkbox?

Tags: android, installation, apk

We are trying to distribute our Android App outside of Google Play. Is there any way to do this without forcing the user to go through the Settings App and checking the "Allow Unknown Sources" checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this without forcing the user to go through the Settings App and checking the "Allow Unknown Sources" checkbox?

If they have the Android SDK installed, they can install your app via USB cable.

Otherwise, they have to check that checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CommonsWare's comment, there is one other way to install. If you can get the manufacturer to sign your app, or if you can somehow get them to install your app from one of their apps, then you can use the following permission:

```
android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
```

Android does not provide this to 3rd party apps, however, so the above two are really your only options.