# How can i install an app from SD Card to device without the need to check 'Unknown source' option

Tags: android, ios, sd-card, android-sdcard

How can i install an app from SD Card to device without the need to check 'Unknown source' option. can the installation from SD card can be done auto? for example: when users inserts SD Card containing only apk, the device auto run the installation permission. Is this possible? Actually i am building an education app for kids,students, and i want to avoid that checking unknown source option for non techno savvy peoples..

Comment: check this link for better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531245/android-apk-distribution-without-unknown-sources-checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically its not possible because of the security limitations. However you can check if the unknown sources is enabled in the settings and prompt user to enable it. Note that it will not work before installing the app.

```
 boolean isNonPlayAppAllowed = false;

                try {
                    isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.Secure.getInt(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;
                } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

if (!isNonPlayAppAllowed) {
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
                }
```

Comment: Thanks. Atleast this will help kid to locate unknown source option and refrain him getting lost in settings options. Can this prompt be activated in realtime as soon as user inserts the SD Card @Prokash Sarkar

Comment: Yes its possible to detect the SD card mount event and execute the prompt. For this the app must need to be installed with "Unknown Sources" enabled. Once the app is installed and the "Unknown Sources" in disabled you can prompt again to enable it.